# How can I make a container resizable?

Tags: forms

I've the body field as container. When I add 
'#resizable' to the field with `hook_form_alter()`, it is not getting resizable.

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_page_form') {
    kint($form);
//      $form['body'] = [
//        '#resizable' => TRUE,
//      ];
  }
}
```

How can I make it resizable?

Comment: Try any one of the these values: #resizable: Controls whether the text area is resizable. Allowed values are "none", "vertical", "horizontal", or "both" (defaults to "vertical").

Comment: @logeshvaran Can you please provide an example on how it is done. I've done that $form['body']['#resizable'] = 'both'; and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Textarea.php/class/Textarea/8.2.x)

says the following:

> "#resizable": Controls whether the text area is resizable. Allowed values are "none", "vertical", "horizontal", or "both" (defaults to "vertical").

in this documentation we can see, that this property "#resizable" is applicable only to textarea.

Then, you can try:

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_page_form') {
    $form['body']['widget']['0']['#resizable']='horizontal';

    //or
    //$form['body']['widget']['0']['#attributes']["style"]="resize:vertical";

  }
}
```

if you change the text format in "**restricted HTML**" you will see

[image]

if you want to use the "both" parameter

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_page_form') {
      $form['body']['widget']['0']['#resizable']='both';

  }
}
```

if you change the text format in "restricted HTML" you will see:

[image]

Comment: Both didn't work for me

Comment: Wait a moment please

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra Did it work?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work.